# How to compare pip versioning with debian versioning?

Tags: python, pip, versioning, packaging

For example if we have a package with version like "1.0.0", then it changes versioning to "0.0.10" epoch will be added. So if we compare it in package way "1:0.0.10" > "1.0.0" there is true. But pip does not has epochs, so it will take the latest according to dates of changes = "0.0.10", I think. So, how this two versions ("0.0.10" and "1.0.0") could be correctly compared (using python for example)?

Answer (score 1):

According to PEP 0440 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#version-scheme)

> Final releases within a project MUST be numbered in a consistently increasing fashion, otherwise automated tools will not be able to upgrade them correctly

Therefore the version after 1.0.0 MUST be 1.0.1 OR 1.1.0 OR 2.0.0.

**EDIT : As you pointed out, there is actually a support for epochs with python and PIP. So you have to use 1!0.0.10 to tell python that your version is actually newer than the 1.0.0. Note that you will have to keep the 1! in all further releases. If you happen to change again the numerotation it would then be 2!1.0.0 and so on.**

Comment: Thank you, but according to this documentation I was wrong and there are epochs (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#version-epochs)! Also this rule applied only for version part. So, pip could have "1.0.0" and "1!0.0.10" versions within one project! :)

Comment: You are actually right, I never used that functionnality, glad you found your answer but anyway I will edit my answer as I was wrong.